# How to reduce the size of javascript when using React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React project that uses Webpack and the initial loading of the React code is really large and slow. I have tried lazy-loading react components and gzipping the files. I can't get the big main.js part smaller or split up. How is this usually done?

My index.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
const Selecter = React.lazy(() => import('./Selecter.js'));
const Displayer = React.lazy(() => import('./Displayer.js'));


function init() {
    const template = (
        <div>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading selector...</div>}>
                <Selecter />
            </Suspense>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading display...</div>}>
                <Displayer />
            </Suspense>
        </div>
    );
    const root = createRoot(document.querySelector("#content"));
    root.render(template);
}

init();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using production build because webpack does most of the optimization there. and if that does not work check out chromes lighthouse panel
for further JavaScript optimization.